# image not shwoing in window in Opencvsharp with intel realsense camera

Tags: c#, opencv

I have made an image using the opencvsharp but when I want to open the image it shows a gray screen.
This is the code I use:

```
using (var frames = pipeline.WaitForFrames())
{
   var colorFrame = frames.ColorFrame.DisposeWith(frames);
   var depthFrame = frames.DepthFrame.DisposeWith(frames);
   Mat test = new Mat(depthFrame.Height, depthFrame.Width, MatType.CV_16UC1, depthFrame.Data);
   using (OpenCvSharp.Window window = new OpenCvSharp.Window("Camera"))
   { 
        window.ShowImage(test);
   }
```

the rest of the code is the same as librealsense from github: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/csharp
does anyone know why the image is not showing in the window

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this question. It is very simple.
After the ShowImage needs a WaitKey(0) for it to show.
That is all